# What affect on available free memory does the size of memory requested by mmap have?

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-management

I understand that memory requested by mmap isn't actually used until it's read or written to.  So in the following test case:

```
int main()
  {
  char *A=mmap(NULL,1073741824/4, PROT_WRITE|PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS,-1,0); 
  *A='a';
  char *B=mmap(NULL,1073741824/4, PROT_WRITE|PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS,-1,0);
  *B='b';
  char *C=mmap(NULL,1073741824/4, PROT_WRITE|PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS,-1,0);
  *C='c';
  char *D=mmap(NULL,1073741824/4, PROT_WRITE|PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS,-1,0);
  *D='d'
  char *E=mmap(NULL,1073741824/4, PROT_WRITE|PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS,-1,0);
  }
```

Am I correct in assuming that memory available to other programs has only reduced by 16k (4 x 4096)?  I don't see any greater reduction in free memory using `free()`, so I assume so.

That being the case, supposing I have an application that generally uses 10MB of memory but on very rare occasions can suddenly need up to 1GB (with as little delay as possible).  Would it be a viable solution to mmap 1GB of memory at the start?  Presumably, while only 10MB is being used, the remaining 990MB is available to other applications.  When the rare occasion occurs that 1GB is needed, I assume there would be much less delay than having to malloc or realloc.

When the extra 990MB is no longer needed, would it be a viable solution to mremap to 10MB and then back to 1GB so as to release the 990MB that is no longer immediately needed, but still provide instant access to it for next time?  I assume this would be much faster than a realloc operation?

Some of all of my assumptions here may be incorrect.  I am trying to gain a better understanding of how mmap affects free memory, and the performance implications of mremap vs using malloc and realloc.

The above is based on a modern linux kernel, using gcc, assuming a 4k page size and portability beyond that, not a significant priority.

Comment: Consider using `madvise(...., MADV_DONTNEED)` instead of unmap/remap when you no longer need the memory.  This can also be used on (part of) a large malloc'ed block if you no longer need the contents, but want to keep it allocated for later use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most processors when running Linux you're correct. A `mmap` of a gigabyte of space will take up only a few KB. It's more than your 16kb because "page tables" have to be allocated to keep track of the memory addresses you've allocated, but not *much* more.

A modern `malloc` will normally use `mmap` almost directly for large allocations so if you `malloc` a huge space you'll get almost the same effect as using `mmap` directly ... probably (but not guaranteed).

One thing you should probably do is add `MAP_NORESERVE` to your flags (if it's defined) to make sure that the space isn't actually allocated somewhere. On Linux this flag *usually* has little (or no) effect but for particular configurations of recent kernels the `mmap` **will** be allocated in swap unless you give this flag.

Do note, however, that some Unixes (and, I think, some processor types under Linux) you will not be able to allocate as much address space. You should be prepared to try again with a smaller mapping if the `mmap` is refused.

One last thing, if you mmap the huge space and Linux later finds that it's too far over subscribed it will kill processes. Make sure you have **excessive** amounts of swap space. You can justify it by having a 30GB tmpfs on /tmp (with 8GB of RAM).

Comment: s/lower limits/upper limits/g

Comment: There are always limits, but they could be lower; I'll rephrase :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably worth doing the large up-front allocation, not because of what *physical* memory is used by your program, but because of *virtual* memory. On 32-bit systems, if you have a fragmented heap, it's quite likely that there will not be any possible 1G allocation to be made. But if you allocate that first, the smaller fragments are more likely to arrange themselves properly.

On 64-bit systems, running *out* of virtual address space is not a problem, but I suspect there are still advantages to allocating it up-front. You might look into `madvise(MADV_HUGEPAGE)` to save pagetable space.

Also, you can `madvise(MADV_DONTNEED)` instead of `mremap`.